# Removing Magento 2 module manually

Tags: magento2

I removed the folder app/code//, removed entry from setup_module table, removed entry from config file and dropped tables from DB. But the code is still being referenced somewhere. I am unable to proceed with any command. Below is the error.

```
PHP Warning:  require(/chroot/home/abc/abc.com/html/vendor/composer/../payu/magento2-payment-gateway/registration.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /chroot/home/abc/abc.com/html/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 70
PHP Warning:  require(/chroot/home/abc/abc.com/html/vendor/composer/../payu/magento2-payment-gateway/registration.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /chroot/home/abc/abc.com/html/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 70
PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/chroot/home/abc/abc.com/html/vendor/composer/../payu/magento2-payment-gateway/registration.php' (include_path='/chroot/home/abc/abc.com/html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library:.:/opt/nexcess/php71u/root/usr/share/pear:/opt/nexcess/php71u/root/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /chroot/home/abc/abc.com/html/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 70
```

Comment: try to remove cache and generated folders

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have installed the module using the composer, so you will have to remove it using composer. Please follow the below steps to unistall a module if it installed using composer. I would suggest you to paste that module in it's location and install it back and then run the below commands:

```
php bin/magento module:disable <Vendor_Module> --clear-static-content
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
composer remove Vendor/Module
```

Answer (score 1):

This error happens because you have installed **payu extension using** composer but you have this extension manually.So you have to remove this extension from composer also.Run below code

> composer remove payu/magento2-payment-gateway --no-update